# Multiplicative functions $\phi : M_n(F) \longrightarrow F$ with $\phi(I) = 1$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $F$ be an infinite field and let $f  \in F[x_{11},x_{12},...,x_{nn}]$ be an **arbitrary**  polynomial in $n^2$ variables. Consider the function  $\phi : M_n(F)\longrightarrow F$ defined by $\phi((a_{ij})) = f(a_{11},a_{12}, ..., a_{nn})$ and suppose that $\phi(I_n) = 1$ and $\phi(AB)= \phi(A)\phi(B)$, for any $A,B \in M_n(F)$. Is it true that $f$ is equal to some power of the determinant (considered as a polynomial of $n^2$ valiables $x_{ij}$).

**Comment:** When $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial then  the problem is known to be true but I have no idea for the general case.

Comment: What is the reference for the homogeneous case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Classically, there is a group endomorphism
$g$ of $F^*$ such that $\phi(M)=g(\det M)$ for all non-singular $M$
(this is obvious if $|F|=2$, otherwise one uses the fact that $[GL_n(F),GL_n(F)]=SL_n(F)$). 
Then, $g$ is a polynomial map from $F$ to itself that satisfies $g(XY)=g(X)g(Y)$. From there, it is easy to see that $g : x \mapsto x^k$ for some 
non-negative integer $k$. Thus, $f(M)=(\det M)^k$ for all non-singular $M$; thus
$(f-\det^k)\det$ vanishes everywhere on $M_n(F)$, 
and hence it is zero as $F$ is infinite. Therefore, $f=\det^k$.

Comment: Why must $g$ be a polynomial?  It is not always true that if $\varphi = g \circ f$ as functions and $\varphi$ and $f$ are polynomials, then so is $g$.  E.g. take $F = \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x^3$, $\varphi(x) = x$.

Comment: Restrict $f$ to the space of all diagonal matrices in which the last $n-1$ entries equal $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition implies that $\phi$ defines a homomorphism $GL_n(F)\rightarrow F^*$. Any such homomorphism annihilates the commutator subgroup $SL_n(F)$, hence factors as $GL_n(F) \,{\buildrel {\det}\over {\longrightarrow}}\,F^*\,{\buildrel {\lambda }\over {\longrightarrow}}\, F^*$, where $\lambda $ is a homomorphism. Since $\lambda \circ \det $ is a polynomial in $(a_{ij})$, $\lambda $ must be given by a polynomial in one variable, and this implies $\lambda (x)=x^n$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: By definition $SL_n(F)$ is the kernel of $\det: GL_n(F)\rightarrow F^*$, so $\det$ provides an isomorphism $GL_n(F)/SL_n(F){\buildrel {\sim}\over {\longrightarrow}}F^*$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a theorem of Schur that every polynomial representation of $GL(n)$ is a direct sum of homogeneous representations, so the general result follows. For a lot of information on this, check out J. A. Green's Polynomial Representations of GL_n (Spring LNM 830).